# What is the correct way to use dlopen() on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, dlopen

I have a shared object bundled with my Android app. It is in the `lib` folder of the APK. On Android 7 I can just do the following to load it:

```
lib = dlopen("libfoo.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

However, this doesn't work on Android 4. On Android 4 I have to do the following instead:

```
lib = dlopen("/data/data/<my_package_identifier>/lib/libfoo.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

So do I always have to specify the path `/data/data/<id>/lib` when calling `dlopen()` on Android? I'm a bit worried about hard-coding paths but as I said, just passing the name of the shared object doesn't work on Android 4.

I know that it is probably easier from the Java side using `System.loadLibrary()` but I don't want to use that either because it doesn't allow me to unload libraries.

Comment: Actually, trying to open the lib from `/data/data/<id>/lib` doesn't work on Android 7. So I don't know how to make this work at all because the first version doesn't work on Android 4 and the second version doesn't work on Android 7. How can I make it work on both versions?

Comment: Ok, so of course I could first try to open `libfoo.so` and it that fails try `/data/data/<id>/lib/libfoo.so` but of course this still feels a little hackish...